# what is the difference between fair channel and fair lossy channel

Tags: system, channel, distribute

Recently I am reading the book "fault-tolerant message passing distributed system", and it involves these two concepts about the channel. However I can not figure out how to understand them and what  they can do, even with their descriptions in the book.
[image]

Only thing I know is fair channel with different msg type but fair lossy channel with the same msg type. Anyone can help me? thanks.

I search from GPT, and its answer is below, which seems a little different from this book.
[image]